# How do I change the case of text in a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

So I'm trying to make a selected amount of text (in a rich text box) go uppercase or go lower case, when that option is clicked in a contextmenu.

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
private void toUPPERCASEToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rtxtMain.SelectedText != "")
            {
                rtxtMain.SelectedText.ToUpper();
            }
        }

private void toLowercaseToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rtxtMain.SelectedText != "")
            {
                rtxtMain.SelectedText.ToLower();
            }
        }
```

However, when I try it out, the text doesn't change... How do I make it change?

Answer (score 11):

You cannot change an existing string instance. ToUpper() and  ToLower() return a new string instance.

Try

```
rtxtMain.SelectedText = rtxtMain.SelectedText.ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 6):

Strings are immutable in C#. Thus, all the built-in operations, including not only `ToLower` and `ToUpper` but also `Replace`, `Trim`, etc., will return new strings containing the modified data. They will not change your existing string.

This is the reason why, as the rest of the posters have noted, your answer is

```
rtxtMain.SelectedText = rtxtMain.SelectedText.ToUpper();
```

Comment: +1 for explaining something the OP didn't appear to understand, beyond just providing a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
rtxtMain.text =ttxtMain.text.Replace(rtxtmain.SelectedText,rtxtmain.SelectedText.ToUpper())
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, alternatively, if you want to do it the hard way, here is the alternative.

```
private void btnCAPS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int start = rtbTheText.SelectionStart;
        int end = start + rtbTheText.SelectedText.Length;
        string oldValue = rtbTheText.SelectedText;
        string newValue = rtbTheText.SelectedText;
        newValue = newValue.ToUpper();
        string partOne = rtbTheText.Text.Substring(0, (start));
        string partTwo = newValue;
        string partThree = rtbTheText.Text.Substring((end));
        
        string replacement = partOne + partTwo + partThree;
        rtbTheText.Text = replacement;
    }
}
```